# Sourcetree seems to ignore protected branch rules

Tags: git, github, branch, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm setting up protected branches so that you need to do a pull request with one approval. so I have a develop branch (protected) and main branch (protected).

I set up the rules for both branches on GitHub.com.
[image]

Now, in SourceTree, I can still merge a feature branch into both develop and main without a pull request, using the [right click >> merge] option.
[image]

The changes are applied right away from the feature branch into develop. What is going on here? shouldn't it prevent me from doing that and instead ask me to submit a pull request?

Edit to clarify: I can then push the merge to GitHub from sourctree and when I go to Github.com the changes from the feature branch are now in the develop branch with no pull request needed.

Comment: Protection, if applied, happens *on GitHub*, in the *GitHub* repository. SourceTree works locally *on your laptop* in a *different repository* (your own personal clone). Protections applied by France to French citizens have no enforceablity on Canadians in Quebec, even if Quebec is vaguely French.

Comment: But source tree lets me push to origin. Making the French end up in Quebec despite being Interdit!

Comment: If the branch on GitHub is protected, the `git push` from SourceTree *should* fail. That's a matter for the French, er, GitHub, gendarmes; contact them. :-)

Comment: To add clarity I push, then check GitHub.com and the changes from the feature branch are now in Develop.

Comment: I'm not completely up on *how* the GitHub rules are supposed to work, but that seems inconsistent with the checkboxes you're showing. Again, this is an issue for GitHub themselves.

Answer (score 0):

This is [the intended behavior from Github](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-protected-branches/about-protected-branches#do-not-allow-bypassing-the-above-settings):

> By default, the restrictions of a branch protection rule do not apply to people with admin permissions to the repository or custom roles with the "bypass branch protections" permission in a repository.

I don't know if it was available at the time of writing, but now you can check the last checkbox from the list stating:

**Do not allow bypassing the above settings**

> The above settings will apply to administrators and custom roles with the "bypass branch protections" permission.